# HTML/Javascript inking or drawing control suggestions?

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking for something that will allow users to write out a signature in an HTML form.  I am looking for something that will run locally on the machine so if it can be done through a javascript function or something else that would be great.

I have seen the canvas HTML5 object, but I haven't found any examples that work well with IE.  I am continuing to look, but was just wondering if anyone knows of anythign else out there that will allow a user to write out a signature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do that with Flex or Silverlight, if you're not averse to plugins.

Otherwise, the only way I can think of to do this would be to create a function that places a very small graphic of a 1 pixel dot over and over again at the point of the cursor when it is dragged with the mouse button depressed. (Depressing, eh?) The dots would replicate more profusely and create a thicker line where the cursor pauses, and make a thinner line as it moves faster. The dots would in any case be close enough together to appear as a line, the way halftone printing uses dots to make photographs appear in newspapers.

I could write this for you but you'd have to pay me. :)

Answer (score 0):

not really 'anything else', but canvas can be made to work even in msie6 with google's excanvas (which maps canvas to vml iirc).

[canvas painter](http://caimansys.com/painter/) does this, just successfully drew my signature in both ff3.6 and msie6, so that might make for a good starting point?